# how to view all images in android's built- in gallery from a php page

Tags: android

I am developing an application to display all the images in android's built-in gallery in to a php page. I posted the uri (`content://media/extrenal/images/media`) of the gallery images to the php page. I was not able to recreate images by using webView's function `loadUrl()`.

Should I need to upload the whole gallery to another directory and display the images?
Or passing the bitmap itself will do?

Please suggest me an idea to solve the problem.

Comment: Why do you want to show your images inside a webview? what's the point?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make an ashynchronous connection of your application with an php application on the server, which will tell the android app to upload the requested image, and when the java app receives the upload command, make the app upload the picture to the server, and make the server php app display the image uploaded. I know this is a bit complicated, but this is the only thing that is comparatively easier than doing socket transports and other things. Good luck :)